# Importing "zst" files?

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to download the smallest file from this website (https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/), i.e. https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/RC_2005-12.zst. My goal is to import this file into R and then query this file to find comments containing certain terms. For example, I want to find every comment that contains the word "tacos".

I have downloaded this file on to my computer, now I would like to try and import this file into R. I have never heard or worked before with this file extension format. I tried to read on the Internet how might I be able to import this file into R.

I did some reading online and found the following package: https://github.com/thekvs/zstdr. However, it doesn't seem like I am able to install this package:

```
> install.packages('zstdr')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘zstdr’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

**Does anyone know how I can import this zst file into R and then query it for specific search terms (e.g. "basketball")? Is there some standard way to import ZST files into R?**

This is the error message I get when trying to install this same library from github:

```
 > devtools::install_github("thekvs/zstdr")

Downloading GitHub repo thekvs/zstdr@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                           
2: CRAN packages only            
3: None                          
4: Rcpp (1.0.8.3 -> 1.0.9) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates: 
v  checking for file 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqumrUb\remotes710158629f3\thekvs-zstdr-f992e66/DESCRIPTION' (533ms)
-  preparing 'zstdr': (3.9s)
v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories (629ms)
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
-  building 'zstdr_0.1.1.tar.gz'
   Warning: file 'zstdr/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
   Warning: file 'zstdr/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR:  Unix-only package
* removing 'C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/zstdr'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqumrUb/file710783f1c08/zstdr_0.1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

And this is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] htm2txt_2.2.2         dplyr_1.0.9           RedditExtractoR_2.1.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tinytex_0.40      tidyselect_1.1.2  xfun_0.30         remotes_2.4.2     purrr_0.3.4       vctrs_0.4.1       generics_0.1.3    testthat_3.1.4    usethis_2.1.6    
[10] htmltools_0.5.2   yaml_2.3.5        utf8_1.2.2        rlang_1.0.2       pkgbuild_1.3.1    pillar_1.7.0      glue_1.6.2        withr_2.5.0       DBI_1.1.3        
[19] sessioninfo_1.2.2 lifecycle_1.0.1   visNetwork_2.1.0  devtools_2.4.3    htmlwidgets_1.5.4 memoise_2.0.1     evaluate_0.15     knitr_1.39        callr_3.7.0      
[28] fastmap_1.1.0     ps_1.6.0          curl_4.3.2        fansi_1.0.3       cachem_1.0.6      desc_1.4.1        pkgload_1.2.4     jsonlite_1.8.0    fs_1.5.2         
[37] brio_1.1.3        digest_0.6.29     processx_3.5.3    RJSONIO_1.3-1.6   rprojroot_2.0.3   cli_3.3.0         tools_4.1.3       magrittr_2.0.2    tibble_3.1.6     
[46] crayon_1.5.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.2    prettyunits_1.1.1 assertthat_0.2.1  rmarkdown_2.14    rstudioapi_0.13   R6_2.5.1          igraph_1.2.11    
[55] compiler_4.1.3
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you have to install [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) on your device, which is according to wikipedia: "CMake is cross-platform free and open-source software for build automation, testing, packaging and installation of software by using a compiler-independent method".

## Install CMake on your device

You can install by clicking on the link above. Make sure you take the right file depending on your system.

**Windows**

I don't have a windows device, so I am not sure if it's more difficult, but I found probably a good [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_X5Iq9niDE).

**Mac**

I work on MAC so, I installed it by following this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sK4sVg4SRsg), which was quite hard in the beginning but you have to make sure it is installed in applications using a sudo activater.

## Install zstdr on Studio

When CMake is installed on your device you can install the package using the following code:

```
devtools::install_github("thekvs/zstdr")
library(zstdr)
```

Which should work and finally you can import your data using this code:

```
data_file <- file.path(R.home(), "COPYING")
data <- readBin(data_file, raw(), file.info(data_file)$size)
compressed <- zstdCompress(data)
```

Comment: @ Quinten: Thank you so much for your answer! Is "data_file" the name of the ZST file that needs to be imported?

Comment: I will see if it is possible to install this CMAKE software on my computer

Comment: Is it possible that there might be some other way to import ZST files without installing additional software? E.g. strictly through some R package? Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Hi @stats_noob, I am not sure if it is possible without CMake, but luckily this made it possible to install the package. I am looking forward to hearing from you if the installation of both CMake and the package were able to you.

Comment: Also according to this [site](http://facebook.github.io/zstd/), this package is the only package that supports Zstandard.

Answer (score 1):

To install R packages from GitHub you need to use a different approach:
first, install `devtools` R package by running `install.packages("devtools")`. Then install `zstdr` package using `devtools` as follows:

```
devtools::install_github("thekvs/zstdr")
```

Then you can import the `zstdr` package in `R` environment by running `library(zstdr)`.

The usage instructions of `zstdr` are given in the Usage section in link below
https://github.com/thekvs/zstdr

Comment: @ Wasim Aftab: thank you for your answer! I tried installing the library this way but it did not work. I edited my question include the error message. Do you have any ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: looks like that package in unix only! does not compile in windows. take a look at these https://github.com/coolbutuseless/zstdlite
https://www.fstpackage.org/reference/compress_fst.html

Comment: @ Wasim Aftab: Thank you for your reply! I will take a look at this right now!

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain that this package works on Windows. The error says:

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘zstdr’ is not available for this version of R

...which makes me think this may be a *nix-only package. Do you have a Linux (or heck, maybe even a Mac) that you can try this on?